# What do I need to create a USB interface between a PC and a board?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I am making a custom camera that will be interfaced through the USB port to the computer. Currently, the board contains all necessary circuitry to drive the image sensor. It outputs a parallel stream of pixel data and a sample pixel clock. The data is sampled with a NI DAQ board that is in the computer.
I would like to add/create a USB interface to my board, so I do not need to use the NI DAQ.

What options are there to create this interface? What do I have to consider? How complex would it be to write a driver for my board so a computer can recognize it? Any recommended articles to get a general insight on how to approach this problem?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to obtain an FTDI FT232 USB-to-Serial converter. This chip allows the USB to talk directly to a microcontroller through the Rx/Tx pins. By reading the data with the microcontroller, you can control circuitry.

https://msuraj.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/fdsaf1.png

Comment: What kind of microcontroller are you planning to use? Some already have built-in USB capabilities, like the PIC18F2550

Comment: @derstrom8 I do not know yet. I heard about the USB-on-a-chip microcontrollers. So, this is a part of the question: what hardware is popular this days?

Comment: Well I mentioned the two most popular ones I can think of--The FTDI chip and the uC with USB built-in. I'm sure some Atmel chips probably have USB built-in too, but I generally don't use AVRs so I can't give you any part numbers. I recommend looking into the above options though =)

Comment: If you want to use an AVR, a quick google search turned up the AT83C5134: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7683.pdf . It appears to have a built-in USB module, but I did not do much research

Comment: For AVR look at the devices with a "U" in the part number, e.g ATmega32U4, AT90USB126, etc.

Comment: You can also look at the Microchip PIC32MX and PIC32MZ series of microcontrollers. The top end PIC32MZ will give you 2MBytes of program FLASH and 512K bytes of RAM if you need to do some buffering and computational things with your image data before dispatching it over to the PC.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I am still trying to figure out how the communication happens on the board side and the computer side. Then I will be considering what kind of chip to get. I plan to do all preprocessing on the FPGA that drives the sensor. So, plain data transfer, want to do the USB3 interface.

Comment: The computer side talks to the USB library or driver using its specific API. What the chip does depends on which one you pick; most have to deal with the raw packets, although the vendor frequently provides a software stack for that.

Comment: Late bu, what board do you have? Do you have any spare UART lines? What is the data rate you are expecting? is USB a mandatory connection or the intention is to bypass the NI DAQ with some simple cable arrangement between PC and the Board?

Comment: @Umar it's a custom designed board, no standard peripheral interfaces. The output is a bus of pixel data and a clock (for sampling). The task is to transfer this data to the computer, preferably via usb port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may need a lot of bandwidth over the USB interface. One need is to get a chip with a USB PHY and bring that up. Another possibility is to use an FPGA and an external USB PHY chip. This will be more work, but it could give you better performance. Another option is to use a USB FIFO chip which is easier to interface with, and couple that to an FPGA or CPLD.

Edit: If you need on the order of 1 Gbps of bandwidth, I think you have two main options: https://github.com/mossmann/daisho (uses TUSB1310A USB 3.0 PHY) or something similar to run USB 3 directly from the FPGA, or connect via PCI express or a wide parallel bus to a relatively powerful controller that supports USB 3.

Comment: I found something like [EZ-USB® FX3](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=50647), but since I am new to the USB interfacing, how would this Cypress chip be different from FTDI or a USB microcontroller?

Comment: If you want a Gbps of bandwidth, I would recommend a full FPGA solution with a USB 3 PHY chip. I believe there is an open source USB 3 core on github, though I am not familiar with its capabilities.

Comment: No other solution will provide the same order of magnitude of bandwidth, unless you want to connect to a USB 3 capable controller via PCIe.

Comment: Looks like the Cypress controller could be a good bet.  Basically, it can significantly simplify the interface between the EZ-USB and your camera setup as it can handle all of the handshaking and what not internally.  You will probably need to write some code for the internal ARM controller on the EZ-USB chip so that it will properly connect to the host and set up the DMA engine.  After that is working, the interface to the DMA engine itself should be relatively simple.  Looks like the EZ-USB chip can present a 32-bit FIFO interface that can run at 100 MHz, or 3.2 Gbit/sec.

Answer (score 0):

If your circuit already has the requisite smarts to process the data a little bit, use a chip already there to output the image data as UART serial, then pipe that through an FTDI chip. Failing that, you could use another microcontroller (I'm an atmel guy, but there are plenty of options) to bitbang the data coming off the other chip, then output it as serial to an FTDI. If you're feeling brave, you could also use a microcontroller with built in USB capabilities, and have that talk directly to the computer using a virtual serial port. An advantage of programming a chip with native serial is that you have the potential to use some kind of video protocol to stream video to the computer without any custom software.

Comment: Would the serial virtual port allow me to have a comparable bandwidth to USB 3? I need to stream video and lots of it. And implementing virtual serial port would require writing a driver?

Comment: I highly doubt you would get USB 3 performance, that's a very high bar, what kind of bitrate are you after here? A virtual serial port wouldn't require a new driver, modern OSs have that built in, but it would need firmware. Luckily there are people who have done all the hard work for you, the arduino people have done it for the arduino leonardo

Comment: I found [EZ-USB® FX3](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=50647), but I do not know what it is yet. They claim the 5Gb/s performance, but if I could get 1Gb/s, I would be happy.

Comment: @Naz are you really trying to steam video at 1 Gb/s? That is complete insanity, and I highly doubt you'd ever be able to get serial to go that fast. You're starting to get into serious specialized bus engineering here, which is way out of my depth anyway.

Comment: Ok, maybe I over exaggerate a little. It's a 2048x2048 frame at 4fps of 12 bitdepth. So, it's about 200Mb/s. However, if I was doing 30fps, it would be 1.5Gb/s. So, you think the chip I mentioned would not be able to do that?

Comment: @Naz I have no idea, but you should probably look at using some kind of encoding, that bitrate is ridiculous

Comment: You're going to have to compress it to get it over the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768999/what-is-a-good-lossless-video-codec huffyuv is simplest, h264 with zero quantisation best.

Comment: .. although you might be able to transmit it losslessly if you pretended to be a SATA interface. You'd have to write quite a bit of firmware.